# Prove that these $3$ functions are constant given a relation is satisfied by divisors of them

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This particular question was asked in masters exam for which I am preparing and I am not able to solve it .

> Question : suppose $f,g,h$ are functions from the set of positive real numbers into itself  satisfying $f(x)g(y)=h((x^2 +y^2)^{1/2})$ for all $x,y \in(0,\infty)$ . Then show that the three functions $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ,\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ and $\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}$ are all constant .

---

Attempt : I first tried by putting $y=0$ only to realize that $0$ is not in domain of $g(y)$ . I am unable to think about any other approach . I am sorry but cant give any other thing in attempt .

Kindly tell how should I approach this question .

Comment: What relation can you deduce between $f(x)g(y)$ and $f(y)g(x)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer they are equal, but how does it helps?

Comment: What can you deduce about $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ from that?

Comment: @DanielFischer f(x)/g(x)=f(y)/g(y)

Comment: And since that holds for all $x,y$, it follows that $f/g$ is constant. Now try something analogous for $g/h$.

Comment: The other two probably doesn't follow very easily. It might require additional (may be continuity type) assumptions, using which it should follow that the functions are all some form of $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I got $g(y)/ h( /sqrt(x^2+y^2))=g(x)/ h(/sqrt(x^2+y^2))$ but I think that there is a problem removing y or x from sqrt(x^2+y^2) which was not in the one you proved . So , I am unable to proceed. Do you mind adding an answer? It would be really helpful!!

Comment: Daniel Fischer showed [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814219/prove-that-these-3-functions-are-constant-given-a-relation-is-satisfied-by-div#comment7871765_3814219) that there exists a constant $c$ such that $g(y)=cf(y)$ for all $y$. 
Therefore $cf(x)f(y)=h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ for all $x,y$. In particular,  $cf(x)f(x)=h(\sqrt{x^2+x^2})=h(\sqrt{2}x)$. This follows 
$h(x)=cf\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$. So $cf(x)f(y)=cf\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} \right)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I show that $f$ must be of the form  $f(x)=e^{c_1x^2+c_2}$,
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two constants, and your conclusion easily follows.

As noted in DanielFischer's and AlexRavsky's comments, there is a constant $c\gt 0$ such that $g(x)=cf(x)$ for $x\gt 0$, so that $h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=cf(x)f(y)$ for $x,y\geq 0$, or
$\ln(h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}))=\ln(c)+\ln(f(x))+\ln(f(y))$. Putting $H(t)=\ln(h(\sqrt{t}))$ and $F(t)=\ln(f(\sqrt{t}))$ for $t\gt 0$, we deduce

$$
H(x^2+y^2)=\ln(c)+F(x^2)+F(y^2)\ (x,y\gt 0)\tag{1}
$$

or (putting $a=x^2,b=y^2$),

$$
H(a+b)=\ln(c)+F(a)+F(b) \ (a,b\gt 0) \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

Taking $b=a$ in \eqref{2}, we deduce $H(2a)=\ln(c)+F(2a)$ or $H(t)=\ln(c)+2F(\frac{t}{2})$ and hence $H(a+b)=\ln(c)+2F(\frac{a+b}{2})$ ; comparing with \eqref{2} we deduce

$$
F\bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)=\frac{F(a)+F(b)}{2} \ (a,b\gt 0)\label{3}\tag{3}
$$

If we take  $a=x,b=x+2y$ in \eqref{3}, we deduce

$$
F(x+2y)=2F(x+y)-F(x) \ (x,y\gt 0)\label{4}\tag{4}
$$

Replacing $x$ with $x+y$ in \eqref{4}, we deduce $F(x+3y)=3F(x+y)-2F(x)$. More generally, by induction on $k\geq 0$ we have

$$
F(x+ky)=kF(x+y)-(k-1)F(x) \ (x,y\gt 0, k\in{\mathbb N})\label{5}\tag{5}
$$

Now, let $t\in {\mathbb Q}_+\cap [0,1]$, so that $t$ can be written $t=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are integers and $q\geq 1, 0 \leq p \leq q$.
Let $a,b \geq 0$. Suppose that $a\leq b$. Putting $x=a, y=\frac{b-a}{q}$.

For $k=p$ in \eqref{5}, we see that $F((1-t)a+tb)=F(x)+p(F(x+y)-F(x))$.

For $k=q$ in \eqref{5}, we see that $F(b)=F(x)+q(F(x+y)-F(x))$.

Combining those two, we see that $F((1-t)a+tb)=(1-t)F(a)+tF(b)$. When $b\lt a$, we obtain the same equality by a similar argument (tahe $x=b,y=\frac{a-b}{q}$, $k=q-p$ or $q$). So we have just shown :

$$
F((1-t)a+tb)=(1-t)F(a)+tF(b) \ (a,b\gt 0,t\in {\mathbb Q}_+\cap [0,1])\label{6}\tag{6}
$$

Now, let $t\in {\mathbb Q}_+$ with $t\gt 1$. Then $t'=\frac{1}{t}\in (0,1)$, and if we put $a'=a, b'=(1-t)a+tb$, from \eqref{6} we deduce $F((1-t')a'+t'b')=(1-t')F(a')+t'F(b')$, or $F(b)=(1-\frac{1}{t})F(a)+F((1-t)a+tb)$. We thus see that \eqref{6} still holds when $t\in {\mathbb Q}_+$ :

$$
F((1-t)a+tb)=(1-t)F(a)+tF(b) \ (a,b\gt 0,t\in {\mathbb Q}_+)\label{6'}\tag{6'}
$$

Now, let $t\in {\mathbb Q}_-$ with $(1-t)a+tb \gt 0$. Then $|t|\in {\mathbb Q}_+$, so by (4') above we have $F((1-|t|)b+|t|a)=(1-|t|)F(b)+|t|F(a)$, so that (4') still holds when $t$ is negative (on the condition that $(1-t)a+tb \gt 0$) :

$$
F((1-t)a+tb)=(1-t)F(a)+tF(b) \ (a,b\gt 0,t\in {\mathbb Q}, (1-t)a+tb \gt 0)\label{6''}\tag{6''}
$$

But then, by the accepted answer in [another MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851063/are-there-maps-0-infty-to-0-infty-that-are-mathbb-q-affine-but-not?noredirect=1#comment7944785_3851063), we know that $F$ is affine, i.e. $F(x)=c_1x+c_2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two constants.

Returning to $f$, one obtains $f(x)=e^{c_1x^2+c_2}$, which finishes the proof.