# Are there maps $(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ that are ${\mathbb Q}$-affine but not ${\mathbb R}$-affine?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations, axiom-of-choice

For any $F\subseteq {\mathbb R}$, say that a map $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is $F$-affine when $f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ whenever $t\in F$, $x,y,tx+(1-t)y \gt 0$.

My question : can we construct a map  $(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$  that's ${\mathbb Q}$-affine but not ${\mathbb R}$-affine ?

**My thoughts :** $f$ cannot be continuous, obviously. If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_r$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent positive real numbers and $C$ is the cone generated by them (so that $C$ is the set of all $\sum_{k=1}^{r} r_k\alpha_k $ where the $r_k$ are nonnegative rationals), then the map $f : C \to C$ defined by

$$
f\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{r} r_k\alpha_k\bigg)=\beta_0+\sum_{k=1}^{r} r_k\beta_k
$$

(where $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_r$ are positive constants), is $\mathbb Q$-affine. Unfortunately, although there are Hamel bases of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ and we can certainly choose one to contain only positive numbers (replacing each negative base element by its opposite),  some positive real numbers will inevitably have some negative coordinates in this base so this seems to be a dead end.

Also, if $f$ is a solution, $f$ can uniquely be extended to a $\mathbb Q$-affine map ${\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: What happens when you apply $\log$ to your map?

Comment: Also, since $-1$ is definitely a rational, you can most certainly have a Hamel basis of only positive reals.

Comment: Maybe it's worth nothing that $\mathbb R$-affine maps are of the form $x \mapsto ax+b$ because $f(tx) = f(0) + tf(x)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: It is well known that there exist dis-continuous $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Such functions satisfy the property  $f(tx)=t(f(x)$ for all rational $t$ and hence they are $ \mathbb  q$ affine. But they are not $\mathbb R$ affine . [If they are then they would be constant multiples of the identity map]. But I don;t know how to get an example which  maps positive numbers to positive numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Answer to your 1st comment : I'm not aware that the log of an affine map has interesting properties, what's your idea here ? Answer to your 2nd comment : as usual, my wording was unclear and you caught me there. I've edited my question to try and fix that, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We're having the same thoughts ...

Comment: It's a fun question. If we were to replace affine by linear, then the answer would be no. We could extend the linear function to all of $\mathbb{R}$ which would preserve the order and thus would be continuous. But I am not sure whether we can reduce to that case.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven As I noted in my question, we can extend $f$ into a map $g$ that's $\mathbb Q$-affine on all of $\mathbb R$, and then $g-g(0)$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear. Unfortunately, $g$ unlike $f$ does not fix ${\mathbb R}_+$  any more ...

Comment: What about $f:(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)/f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{c} x \mbox{ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\ e^x \mbox{ if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$} \end{array} \right. $ ?

Comment: @astro This is obviously not $\mathbb Q$-affine : for example, $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\neq \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ for $a=\sqrt{2},b=2-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: My bad, I took the definition the other way around. As the teacher said READ THE DATA IN THE QUESTION CAREFULLY lolololol thx @EwanDelanoy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-affine.  Then I claim $f$ is order-preserving.  Indeed, suppose $a<b$ but $f(a)>f(b)$.  Then $qb+(1-q)a>0$ for all $q>0$, so $f(qb+(1-q)a)=qf(b)+(1-q)f(a)$ for all positive rationals $q$.  But when $q$ is sufficiently large, $qf(b)+(1-q)f(a)$ is negative since $f(a)>f(b)$, so this is a contradiction.

Now I claim $f$ is continuous and hence $\mathbb{R}$-affine.  Since $f$ is order-preserving, if $f$ were not continuous, there would be $a<b$ such that the image of $f$ omits an interval contained in $[f(a),f(b)]$. But now note that for any rational $q\in [0,1]$, $f(qa+(1-q)b)=qf(a)+(1-q)f(b)$, and the set of such values is dense in $[f(a),f(b)]$.  Thus the image of $f$ intersects every interval contained in $[f(a),f(b)]$, so $f$ must be continuous.